# VB.NET DataTable rows

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, authentication

I'm trying to make a login form.

I've created a database on my server and created the rows username and password.
I then created a root user with root as password.

but I have a problem with the check if the username and password are correct,
I don't know how to give him the 2 rows.

```
Dim conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=SRV-SQL;Initial Catalog=prova;User ID=user;Password=user")
Dim sda = New SqlDataAdapter("select count(*) from tblLogin where username ='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and password='" + txtUserPwd.Text + "'", conn)
Dim dt = New DataTable()
sda.Fill(dt)
If (dt.Rows().ToString() = "1") Then
    MsgBox("Logged-in successfully")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("The username or the password is wrong!", "Warning!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If
```

**Table:**

[image: table]

Comment: Woah!!! There's a lot wrong with what you have there. Firstly `"username ='" + txtUsername.Text + "'"`. This isn't a parametrised query, and considering the statement you're running, the value of `txtUsername` is coming from user input. This is **wide** open to injection. You need to fix that, now. **Parametrise** your query. Next we have `"password='" + txtUserPwd.Text + "'"`; this *very strongly* implies you are storing password as plain text. As well as that this is also open to injection  **never** store passwords as plain text. They should ideally be hashed and salted.

Comment: As a very quick example, what do you think would happen if someone entered their username as `'; SELECT * FROM sys.tables; DROP TABLE tblLogin;--` or `' CREATE LOGIN SuperAdmin WITH PASSWORD= '123', CHECK_POLICY=OFF, CHECK_EXPIRY = OFF; ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [SuperAdmin];--`?

Comment: Its just a project im making for fun so i wont be uploading it anywhere and its even my first project with SQL

Comment: `If (dt.Rows().ToString() = "1"` does not indicate successful login with the query you're using.  The value of that row could be 1 or 0.  In either case, you will always get a row.  You need to look at the *actual value* that is returned, not just the rowcount.  If you wanted to check via simple rowcount then you would need `SELECT * FROM tblLogin WHERE username=...`.  Or even better, `SELECT 1 FROM tblLogin WHERE username=...`.

Comment: @squillman I don't see anything wrong with the OP Select statement (except it needs to use parameters). Select * will bring down unnecessary data.

Comment: `dt.Rows().ToString()` returns the fully qualified name of the object, System.DataRow.Collection which will never equal "1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments and explanations in-line.

```vb
Private Sub VerifyLogin()
        'For the Return Value of the command
        Dim RetVal As Integer
        ' A Using...End Using will ensure that you connectionis closed and disposed event
        'it there is an error.
        Using conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=SRV-SQL;Initial Catalog=prova;User ID=user;Password=user")
            'You don't need a DataAdapter, just a command
            'USE PARAMETERS. Yes, I am yelling :-) Even if you are the only user
            'it will save you headaches with syntax.
            Using cmd = New SqlCommand("select count(*) from tblLogin where username = @UserName and password= @Password;", conn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUserPwd.Text
                'You are only returning one row
                'ExecuteScalar returns the value in the first column of the 
                'first row of the the data
                conn.Open()
                RetVal = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
            End Using
        End Using
        'No need to convert to a string just compare the Integer
        If RetVal = 1 Then
            MsgBox("Logged-in successfully")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("The username or the password is wrong!", "Warning!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Private Function CalculateHash(password As String, salt As String) As String
    'TODO:
    ' Suggest pulling the BCrypt from the NuGet gallery for this:
    ' https://www.nuget.org/packages/BCrypt-Official/
    ' Just remember that bcyrpt lib encodes salt as part of the password hash, so the function signatures and db table will be different.
End Function

Public Function CheckCredentials(UserName As String, Password As String) As Boolean
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=SRV-SQL;Initial Catalog=prova;User ID=user;Password=user"), _
          ' Need to add a "Salt" column to your table, create a new random salt for each user when you create the user
          cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT Salt, PwdHash FROM tblLogin WHERE username = @Username", conn)

        'Parameterized queries or NOTHING. String concatention is NOT OKAY here
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = UserName

        conn.Open()   
        Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If Not rdr.Read() Then Return False

            Dim Salt As String = rdr("Salt")
            Dim PwdHash As String = rdr("PwdHash")

            'Compare HASHES, not Passwords
            Return PwdHash = CalculateHash(Password, Salt As String)
        End Using
    End Using
End Function

If CheckCredentials(txtUsername.Text, txtUserPwd.Text) Then
    MsgBox("Logged-in successfully")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("The username or the password is wrong!", "Warning!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DataReader instead, use this code and just call CheckLogin in login button or somthing else.

```
Sub CheckLogin()

    Dim conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=SRV-SQL;Initial Catalog=prova;User ID=user;Password=user")

    conn.Open()

    Try

        Dim query As String = "select count(*) from tblLogin where username = @username and password= @password "
        Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(query, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtUserPwd.Text)
        Dim DR As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If DR.HasRows Then

            MsgBox("Logged-in successfully")

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("The username or the password is wrong!", "Warning!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    conn.Close()

End Sub
```